# Prove for a monotone function, if $x_0$ is interior on interval $I$ then the one-sided limits exists

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, functions

**The proof goes like this:**

Lets suppose $f$ is nondecreasing (for nonincreasing we'll observe the function $-f(x)$).

Let $x_0$ an interior point in the interval $I$, and $\left\{x_k\right\}$ an increasing sequence of points in $I$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k = x_0$.

Then, the sequence $\left\{ f(x_k) \right\}$ a nondecreasing sequence which bounded above by $f(x_0)$.
The sequence $\left\{ f(x_k) \right\}$ is monotone and bounded and therefore approaches a limit, $L$.

For $x_k < x < x_0:$ $$f(x_k) \le f(x) \le L$$.
Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $f(x_k)\rightarrow L$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $L-f(x_k) < \varepsilon$ for all $k\ge N$.

For all $x$ satisfying $x_N \le x \le x_0$ we thus have:

$$L-f(x) \le L-f(x_N) \lt \varepsilon$$

It follows that $$\lim_{x\to {x_0}^-} = L$$

**Questions:**

1. The last part of the proof looks to me like a "cosmetic treatment". What is the benefit of this other than changing $x_k$ to $x$.
2. Is this proof rigorous enough? Would you change something or do you think something has to be explained better?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of the proof only proves the following:

> For each increasing sequence $\{x_k\}$ with limit $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k=x_0$, there exists a limit $L$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_k) = L$.

In this part of the proof, there is nothing that shows that all the sequences have the same limit. That is shown in the second part. The second part proves:

> For all $\epsilon$, there exists such a $N$ that for all $x$, $x_N\leq x\leq x_0$, we have $$L-f(x)<\epsilon.$$

Not, to the second part of your question: Is it rigorous? Well, technically, what you need to prove is:

> For all $\epsilon$, there exists such a $\delta$ that for all $x$, $x_0-\delta\leq x\leq x_0$, we have $$L-f(x)<\epsilon.$$

However, given that you know $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty} x_k = x_0$, such a value of $\delta$ is very easy to find.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of 5xum is just what you need.

This is only an alternative way to prove that: $$\lim_{x\to {x_0}^-} = L$$ not making use of sequences.

For $x_{0}\in I$ define $J:=I\cap\left(-\infty,x_{0}\right)$ and
$L:=\sup\left\{ f\left(x\right)\mid x\in J\right\} $.

Clearly $J\neq\emptyset$
and for $x\in J$ we have $f\left(x\right)\leq f\left(x_{0}\right)$.

This together tells us that $L\in\left(-\infty,f\left(x_{0}\right)\right]\subset\mathbb{R}$.

For $\epsilon>0$ find some $z\in J$ with $f\left(z\right)>L-\epsilon$.

Taking $\delta=x_{0}-z>0$ we have $L-\epsilon<f\left(x\right)\leq L$
if $x_{0}-\delta=z<x<x_{0}$